# Typescript invalid character when escaping newline?

Tags: typescript, escaping, newline

I have a simple method where I just concatenate a bunch of strings and format it somewhat readably.

```
info() {
        return    "x:      " + this.xpos.toString() + "\n" \
                + "y:      " + this.ypos.toString() + "\n" \
                + "width:  " + this.width.toString() + "\n" \
                + "height: " + this.height.toString() + "\n";
}
```

I'm aware the code itself isn't amazing, but when I run `tsc`, I get the following error:

```
cli.ts:32:54 - error TS1127: Invalid character.
```

This occurs for all the lines where there is a `\` to escape the newline. What do I need to do to escape a newline in TS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Typescript, you don't need the `\` to be able to break a long line of code into multiple lines like you would in a language like Python. If you remove them, your code will compile again.

Perhaps [template strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) would help organize this a bit?